# How does centre of pressure change with angle of attack?

Tags: aerodynamics, lift, airfoil, angle-of-attack

I've been given the distance of centre of pressure from the leading edge with a certain angle of attack and was wondering if it's possible to calculate the new position when the angle of attack changes.

Comment: Closely related: http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/31878/what-is-the-aerodynamic-centre-and-how-does-it-relate-to-the-pitching-moment/31887#31887

Answer (score 5):

This [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Center_of_pressure_(fluid_mechanics)) explains that the movement of the center of pressure with changes in angle of attack depends on the airfoil shape.
In summary:

- For a symmetric airfoil, as angle of attack and lift coefficient
  change, the center of pressure does not move. It remains around the
  quarter-chord point for angles of attack below the stalling angle of
  attack.
- For a conventionally cambered airfoil, the center of    pressure lies
  a little behind the quarter-chord point at maximum lift coefficient (large angle of attack), but as lift coefficient reduces (angle of attack reduces) the center of pressure moves toward the rear.
- For a reflex-cambered airfoil, the center of pressure lies a little ahead of the quarter-chord point at maximum lift coefficient (large angle of attack), but as lift coefficient reduces (angle of attack reduces) the center of pressure moves forward.

I do not have a simple expression that can be used to predict this movement of the center of pressure, but I suppose a computational fluid dynamics package can be used to model this for the specific airfoils used on the aircraft.

Answer (score 0):

Its not a easy calculation. Even during our engineering we were told how it shifts but never any mathematical solution to it. But I have seen this being calculated on MATLAB.