# What is the relationship between the Center of Pressure and flap deployment?

Tags: aircraft-design, aerodynamics, airfoil

I have been reading regarding the Center of Pressure of an airfoil (Cp) and the relationship with angle of attack.

What is a good way to explain in layman's terms why the pressure changes in such a way as to move the Cp forward as AOA is increased?

Also, in a flap deployment situation; the Cp moves aft. My reasoning here would be because now the aft portion of the airfoil is now at an increased camber, meaning that you have more lift production towards the aft of the airfoil, the Cp (average of the lift production across the wing) would be moving aft. Is this correct?

Comment: Your first question is answered [in the second half of this answer](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/31878/what-is-the-aerodynamic-centre-and-how-does-it-relate-to-the-pitching-moment/31887#31887). I admit it is hard to find. Your assumption for the second question is correct; flaps will change the camber and thus the camber-related pressure distribution.